# can't get to work webcam on WPF c# with multiple cams

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam

I've been working for a while on a WPF application that uses at the same time:

- Leap motion
- Integrated Webcam

I make work everything else but the webcam, I followed a lot of codes/tutorials I found on the internet but did not succeed, the one I followed last time was this one:

https://easywebcam.codeplex.com/

And it worked fine, no problem, easy to do. But now, on my new laptop it just doesnt work, even without Leap disconnected. I always get a green screen or this message "an error occurred while capturing the video image. the video capture will now be terminated".

I checked and the webcam works fine on skype, camera..etc... Leap motion works fine too.

I've heard about using DirectShow, but I don't know where to start.

Thanks for your time mates

Comment: Just a stab in the dark: Maybe the webcam on your laptop has some special weird drivers.

Comment: hm, I also thought the same @Mathew, I'll do some research and publish it here.